# Seaborn heatmap by column

Tags: python, heatmap, seaborn

It seems to me the heatmap function is applied to the dataframe in its entirety.  What if I only want the heatmap applied to a given set of column(s) from my dataset?  I would imagine this can be achieved by smartly using cmap, but cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this questions. I was just about to post this.

Answer (score 13):

Pass the desired sub-DataFrame to [`seaborn.heatmap`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn-dev/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
seaborn.heatmap(df[[col1, col2]], ...)
```

`df[[col1, col2, ..., coln]]` returns a DataFrame composed of the columns `col1`, `col2`, ... `coln` from `df`. Note the double brackets.

---

If you wish to highlight only certain values and plot the heatmap as though all other values are zero,
you could make a copy of the DataFrame and set those values to zero before calling `heatmap`. For example, modifying [the example from the docs](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/heatmap_annotation.html),

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.matrix as smatrix

sns.set()

flights_long = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights_long.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
flights = flights.reindex(flights_long.iloc[:12].month)

columns = [1953,1955]
myflights = flights.copy()
mask = myflights.columns.isin(columns)
myflights.loc[:, ~mask] = 0
arr = flights.values
vmin, vmax = arr.min(), arr.max()
sns.heatmap(myflights, annot=True, fmt="d", vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much was just searching for this and was about to post a question.. got answer without asking.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I actually tried this, but this would only plot the chosen column(s), but not the entire dataset, no?  What I want is to only apply the heatmap to the selected column(s) but other columns need to be still visible.

Comment: What do you mean by the "other columns need to be still visible"? Do mean they should be drawn as though the value in each cell is zero?

Comment: I would not use the `_HeatMapper` object directly unless you a) know what you are doing and b) are ok with your code possibly breaking without warning in the future.

Comment: Yes, I mean the other columns should be drawn as though the value in each cell is a constant( e.g. zero ).  Effectively, I only need the heatmap for one column.

Comment: I tried using masking as well. The problem there is as you illustrated in your example, I don't want to zero out the other columns.

Comment: Sorry then; I don't think I know how to do what you are looking for.