# Show only first column in a correlation matrix in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn, correlation

I have created a correlation matrix of a pandas dataframe using seaborn with the following commands:

```
corrMatrix = df.corr()
#sns.heatmap(corrMatrix, annot=True)
#plt.show()

ax = sns.heatmap(
    corrMatrix, 
    vmin=-1, vmax=1, center=0,
    cmap=sns.diverging_palette(20, 220, n=200),
    square=True, annot=True
)
ax.set_xticklabels(
    ax.get_xticklabels(),
    rotation=45,
    horizontalalignment='right'
);
```

I get the following matrix plot:

[image]

How can you mask the correlation matrix to only show the first column of the matrix? I would also like the legend show along the right side.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `x` is `corrMatrix[['# of Prophages']]`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.rand(8), 'B': np.random.rand(8)})
corr = df.corr()

x = corr[['A']]
sns.heatmap(x)
```

---

**corr:**

```
    A            B
A   1.000000    -0.192375
B   -0.192375   1.000000
```

**sns.heatmap(corr):**

[image]

**sns.heatmap(x):**

[image]

This might help you:

Credit goes to [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31061268/6660373)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.matrix as smatrix

sns.set()

flights_long = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights_long.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
flights = flights.reindex(flights_long.iloc[:12].month)
sns.heatmap(flights)
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

```
columns = [1953]
myflights = flights.copy()
mask = myflights.columns.isin(columns)
myflights.loc[:, mask] = 0
arr = flights.values
vmin, vmax = arr.min(), arr.max()
sns.heatmap(flights, mask=myflights, annot=True, fmt="d", vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

```
columns = [1953]
myflights = flights.copy()
mask = myflights.columns.isin(columns)
myflights = myflights.loc[:, mask]
arr = flights.values
vmin, vmax = arr.min(), arr.max()
sns.heatmap(myflights, annot=True, fmt="d", vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Very well documented! Thank you for the through answer!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on dummy data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(corrMatrix['# of Prophages'],
              index=corrMatrix.index)

sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt="g", cmap='viridis')

plt.show()
```

This was adapted from this answer: [Seaborn Heatmap with single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585775/seaborn-heatmap-with-single-column)

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this question! I guess I can mark my question as a duplicate. This is very helpful.