# How to plot pandas three column with seaborn (calculated with group by)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, seaborn

I have a dataframe looks like this:
[image]

and using code snippet, I calculate species observed each month and their respective count per month (I think only variables are needed to show):

code:

```
state_bird_month_sum = state_bird_month_sorted.groupby(['Month','COMMON NAME'])[['OBSERVATION COUNT']].agg('sum')
state_bird_month_sum
```

that gives me this:

[image]

Basically, there can be multiple species observed in a month and each species has a value 'observation count' associated.

I want to make a plot like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061165/seaborn-heatmap-by-column) where x is 'COMMON NAME', y is 'Month' and annotated values are 'OBSERVATION COUNT'. In general, plot should show the species count (cumulative = all observation counts in a month) for each month.

I tried to plot using seaborn using the code below but doesn't work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

flights = state_bird_month_sum.pivot('Month','COMMON NAME', 'OBSERVATION COUNT')

myflights = flights.copy()

arr = flights.values
vmin, vmax = arr.min(), arr.max()
sns.heatmap(myflights, annot=True, fmt="d", vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the dataframe `state_bird_month_sum`.

```
df_temp = state_bird_month_sum.pivot_table("OBSERVATION COUNT", "COMMON NAME", "Month")

plt.figure(figsize = (25,15))
plt.title("NAME OF THE GRAPH", size=20)
plot = sns.heatmap(df_temp)
plot.set(xlabel="MONTH", ylabel="COMMON NAME")
plt.show()
```